# how to insert ampersand in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

How to insert ampersand in mysql using php?
Thanks in advance

When I execute the following code the “one” is saves in database but the “ second” and ampersand sign won’t. plz help me…

```
$companyName ="one & second"; 
INSERT INTO registeration(companyName) VALUES('". $companyName ."')";
```

Comment: what have you tried till now? what happend? did you get any error-messages?

Comment: When I execute the following code the “one” is saves in database but the “ second” and ampersand sign  won’t.  plz help me…
$companyName ="one & second";
INSERT INTO registeration(companyName) VALUES('". $companyName ."')";

Comment: How do you see what has been saved in the database?

Comment: "plz help me" isn't a question. What debugging have you done? BTW it's "registration"

Comment: The question was so clear to me. The &ampersand is not been inserted. What else @Kushai need to explain???

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but I just ran into this issue myself and the issue turned out to be an escaping issue with ajax post rather than an issue with mysql and php.  I added encodeURIComponent(*variabletopost*) to the variable before posting it with ajax and it worked great.

Comment: ... which means you had no issue with SQL at all, but with some other technology, and failed to break down your problem into component pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same way as any other data, no special action required.

Answer (score 1):

`insert into table (field) values ('&')`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but,
try adding `addslashes()` to your php var:

```
$companyName = addslashes("one & second");
```

Then, when php parses the '&' (ampersand) , it reads '\&' (backslash-ampersand) instead of trying to create a reference in the middle of the query.

Comment: why am I getting marked down? I was having the exact problem described by the original poster. This was the solution that worked for me.

PHP uses '&' to reference variables. Since, there is no variable after the '&', it references nothing, I suppose. But, if the string is being parsed by PHP, depending on whether or not single or double quotes are used: If the the '&' is not escaped, it will be taken literally, and not as part of the string. php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: Your answer (not *you* personally) was downvoted for this statement: `If the the '&' is not escaped, it will be taken literally` which doesn't make any sense. An ampersand char doesn't have no special meaning inside of PHP strings nor in SQL.

Comment: 1. from the PHP documentation: '&' needs to be escaped:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
2.'&' is an operator in both PHP and MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.return

so, I am being downvoted for quoting PHP documentation? 
how does this site work, exactly?

Comment: Sorry for being argumentative, but, the original poster is using double quotes, not single, in the statement. according to the docs, if using double quotes, '&' needs to be escaped. Another option, would be to simply use single quotes around 'first & second' instead of double quotes.

Maybe PHP isn't trying to create a reference to nothing, but the '&' is breaking the query, because it's being treated as an operator, not part of the string.

Comment: the PHP docs you are quoting says nothing about escaping `&`. Read it first yourself. And & is not breaking the query. Try to learn first and use no guessing but knowledge in solving problems.

Comment: I was. the solution I offered worked on several servers for me.

Comment: OMG, IT CANNOT WORK. addslashes will add nothing to ampersand. You can verify it with one line of code - apply addslashes to a string and then compare with source. Your "it worked" but a superstition. A wild superstition.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced this type of issue and solved by using javascript function encodeURIComponent(uri);

In place of uri you have to put your variable. then it will allow all special character.